# Auth::logout() prioritizing above all code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on a project wich needs an online status on the user so i just added an on auth.logout event to listen for logouts and put the status to false for offline. In the event when logged the $event->user value is null. So I tried checking the function that calls Auth::logout() in my project and for some reason the code is being triggered before all the other code. Any one has any idea ?

Here it still has the User Model data.

```
protected function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $user->online = 0;
    $user->save()
    //Auth::logout();

    return redirect()->intended(route('page.login'));
}
```

But here the $user = null

```
protected function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user(); //$user = null
    $user->online = 0;
    $user->save();
    Auth::logout(); //Is this taking priority over all code somehow ?

    return redirect()->intended(route('page.login'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is absolutely no way that code is jumping precedence. If that was possible, software development would be an impossible feat of coincidence and magic -- more so than it already is.

It's much more likely that that code is executing twice. Try setting up the controller logic so that it can function if $user is null. I would bet money that `logout()` is running multiple times.

```
protected function logout()
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    if ($user)
    {
        $user->online = 0;
        $user->save();
        Auth::logout();
    }

    return redirect()->intended(route('page.login'));
}
```

Comment: That worked thanks :) i guess Auth::logout() also triggers the logout function